# add userid parameter to route configuration in ZF pagination

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php 
echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'sliding','partial/paginator.phtml',array('route' => 'adminuserlog'));
?>
```

My error is:

```
Missing parameter "userid"
```

How do I go about appending the userid param to the route portion of the call? The value of the user id is `$this->user->getId()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of the `PaginationControl` viewHelper is the way to pass data to your pagination partial/view.

```
echo $this->paginationControl(
    $this->paginator,
    'sliding',
    'partial/paginator.phtml',
    array(
        'route' => 'adminuserlog',
        'routeParams' => array('userId' => $this->user->getId())
    ),
);
```

As the `partial/paginator.phtml` is just a view we can access any view variable by either using `$route` or `$this->route`.

Update your `partial/paginator.phtml` file to include the `$routeParams`:

```
$routeParams = isset($this->routeParams) && is_array($this->routeParams) ? $this->routeParams : [];
$queryParams = isset($this->queryParams) && is_array($this->queryParams) ? $this->queryParams : [];

$urlOptions = ['query' => $queryParams];

// Rendering a button and usage of the URL viewhelper
<a href="<?= $this->url(
    $route,
    $routeParams,
    ArrayUtils::merge($urlOptions, ['query' => ['page' => $this->first]])
); ?>">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
</a>
```